# composer autoload psr-4 - можно ли сделать не регистра зависимым?

Tags: php, composer

У нас на проекте используется autoload psr-4, настроен через композер.

Возможно ли сделать загрузку классов не регистра зависимым?
Т.е. в файловой структуре наименование папок и файлов с маленькой буквы, а в неймспейсах использовать названия с заглавной буквы, а наименовая классов точно также, и как и при описании класса?

Т.е. `vendorname/ns/someclass.php`

```
<? 
namespace vendorName\NS;

class someClass {
   ...
}
```

И уже вызывать класс таким образом: `vendorName/NS::someClass` ?

Comment: Первое, **SomeClass**, а не *someClass*. Второе, регистронезависимость зависит от ОС. Если в винде у вас может быть всё пучком, то в никсах работать ничего не будет

Comment: Попробуйте для этого воспользоваться автозагрузкой  `"class-map" : ["folder1/", "folder2/"]` вместо `psr-4`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1803
На подобное предложение авторы композера уперлись "это повлияет на производительность". Разные люди описывали свои неудобства - пофиг.

Авторы уперлись, что один "if" будет тормозить весь интернет :)

Мне был ответ "вы можете написать свой автолоадер и не использовать существующий"